# Location of a session and how to retrieve it

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I use the following to connect to an Oracle database and issue queries:

```
import cx_Oracle

dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('1.2.3.4.5', 1521,'xe')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect('test', 'test', dsn_tns)
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from sales')
```

At what level is the `session` located? For example, is `dsn_tns` the object that contains the session, and both the `conn` and `cursor` and any `queries` that run will be contained within that session? Or, is it located somewhere else? How can I retrieve the session ID for this particular user?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Session ID of a sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565952/session-id-of-a-sql-query)

Comment: The session is located in the connection object. Check out the hyperlink I gave above for a way to get the session id.